# How to use Redux devtools with Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use the Redux DevTools extension on my Next.js application. The redux is working fine but I'm not being able to see the state in the devtools.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**_app.js**:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

let store;

function initStore(initialState) {
    const composeEnhancers = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  return createStore(
    reducers,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
    )
  )
}

function useStore(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeStore(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}

const initializeStore = (preloadedState) => {
  let _store = store ?? initStore(preloadedState)

  if (preloadedState && store) {
    _store = initStore({
      ...store.getState(),
      ...preloadedState,
    })
    store = undefined
  }

  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _store
  if (!store) store = _store

  return _store
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using next-redux wrapper and this is how I set it:

```
const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
   // I require this only in dev environment
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

export const makeStore = (context) => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    bindMiddleware([thunk])
  );
  return store;
};
```

Comment: Also using `next-redux-wrapper` but without middleware:

`const composeEnhancers =
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;
const makeStore = (context) => createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers());`

Just make sure you import `compose` from redux.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that devtools only runs in the browser, as nextjs is a framework that execute javascript in node before it comes to the browser.

Solution? add the condition **if (typeof window !== 'undefined')** to the *composeEnhancers* section. I did something like this in my code:

```
// ---Redux DevTools
let composeEnhancers = compose;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}
```

This ensures your redux devtools configuration only runs in the browser :D

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you would see that your suggestion is already included in the shared code.

Comment: Hey Steven. This answer worked thank you very much you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've tried to use the beta version of the nextjs with the app folder instead of pages -> _app.tsx. And my redux dev tools were always showing like this:

[image]

**Solution**:
Follow this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux) and start using _app.tsx

Answer (score -1):

using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

=>

```
const store = createStore(   todoReducer,   typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    : null );
```